# How to assign shortcut to play button when using Rider with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

Using Rider, I can debug my unity project but sometimes, I just want to run the project without debugging it. Is there any way to bind a shortcut to the play button (Play/Edit).

How could I do that with last version of Rider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know this is done using this button

[image]

And yes, you can assign a shortcut for that button!

- Open the `File` → `Settings` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
- Go to `Keymap` → `Plugins`

  [image]
- Scroll down to `Unity Support` and find the `Play/Edit` button

  [image]
- Right click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

  [image]
- Add whatever appealing yet unused shortcut is availble (good luck finding one :P)

  [image]
- Hit `Ok` and `Save` → Happy ;)

  [image]